# C# - Getting Socket Exception connection attempt failed even after entering correct hostname and port

Tags: c#, sockets, email

Unable to connect Outlook through POP. 
Getting Socket exception Message
"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 52.97.232.194:995"
I have also enabled the access of POP from Outlook settings

This line of code is causing exception

```
EmailClient.client.Connect("outlook.office365.com", 995, true);
```

[See this for complete reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S13Pb.png)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> EmailClient.client.Connect("outlook.office365.com", 995, true);
> ```

This is not what is shown in the image with the error. While you claim to use port 995 based on this question in the actual code you use port 993. Only, this is not the correct port for POP3s, it is instead the port for IMAPs. The client will not receive the expected greeting line from the POP3 server but instead receive the greeting from an IMAP server.

Comment: Ok my bad , so what will be the port for pop3 .

Comment: @ShahanMustafa: 995 would be the correct port for POP3. But the image with the error you include in your question clearly shows that you did not use 995 as claimed in the question but 993 instead in the actual code.